# Missing : after property id syntax error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a syntax error from the code below:

```
(function({ 
  var resultsDIV = document.getElementById("results"),
    searchInput = document.forms[0].search,
    currentSearch = ''
  ;
```

I have tried all sorts of ways of writing this line but continue to get the same error.

The actual error I am getting is:

> "Syntax Error: missing : after property id"

Can anyone help?

Comment: show a bit more context, please.

Comment: to me, using a plural sustantive to define a unique id is a wrong start.

Comment: I think you forgot to include the syntax error.

Comment: The first key to finding syntax errors is to look at the surrounding lines as well. Can you include more context?

Comment: It appears you have an unclosed object literal, probably on the line above.

Comment: Thank you everyone, in particular Blender

Comment: If you found one of the answers useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`(function({` should be `(function(){`.

Answer (score 0):

For me miss `;` or you not declared the id in one tag.

Example:

```
<p id="po"></p>
```

After with the update's question:

```
(function(){

var resultsDIV = document.getElementById("results");
    searchInput = document.forms[0].search;
    currentSearch = '';
})();
```